# Given the lack of a gender-neutral pronoun in French, how should one refer to somebody of unknown gender?

Tags: choix-de-mot, genre, genre-biologique, pronoms

Is there a specific rule on how you should refer to someone of unknown gender in French?  For example, if you were writing a guide on how to do something and you wanted to indicate that the reader should do something, which of the below (or something else?) would it be best to write?

> Il doit faire...
>   Elle doit faire...
>   On doit faire...
>   Il faut faire...

This question also applies if someone's gender is in dispute; how would you refer to that person?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In French we are not as surprised if “*une personne*” relates to a man and if “*quelqu'un*” is a woman.  (Yet feminine words like “*personne*” which may easily refer to a man are quite rare, currently I can just think of “*sentinelle*”, “*estafette*”, “*recrue*”, “*ordonnance*”, all four from the military vocabulary BTW, “*personnalité*”, “*victime*” and “*connaissance*”; there are probably a few other expressions like “*grande gueule*”).

Even if you try to be less obvious with masculine terms (using *on*, the plural, the second person, …), the rules of French are such that the masculine will still be present.  Trying to be real neutral is harder and more non natural than in English.

It is perhaps why this matter is less sensitive than in English, at least from a male perspective (a female view would be welcome). The convention is to use the masculine; doing otherwise is more often than not a political statement.

Note that while the rule *le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin* is often stated and used, there is a quite strong usage to use feminine name for professions mostly feminine (for example, people will use *institutrice* to refer to the teacher of unknown sex for small children, the use of *infirmières* to refer to the whole profession is also common).

Answer (score 14):

When I was at school, we were told to start letters with *Cher Monsieur* if we didn't know the gender of the person we were writing to. At the time, I believe the rule was to assume masculine until proven otherwise.

This behaviour mimics the fact that a mixed plural is always masculine too (*Paul et Marie sont grands* whereas *Paul est grand* and *Marie est grande*). The saying goes *le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin* (masculine wins over feminine).

Similarly, it is usual to refer to the reader as *le lecteur* ; for example *le lecteur intéressé se réfèrera au livre de Jules Dubonnet* (The interested reader should consult the book by Jules Dubonnet).

However, there are people who believe<sup>[citation needed]</sup> this is a way of asserting a male superiority and that it's unfair towards women. The saying *le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin* in itself it particularly eloquent and can be understood as "men win" if taken out of a pure grammatical context (which it shouldn't be).

As such, if you want to keep a neutral stance, it may be better to either mention both (*Chère madame, cher monsieur*) or maybe use a plural (*Les lecteurs intéressés se réfèreront au livre de Jules Dubonnet*) which, even if it's still masculine, tacitly encompasses female readers too.

Comment: Seems like English, only with less feminist influence.  :-)

Comment: @Jez, in a language where beard is feminine and vagina is masculine, taking political-correctness down to the level of grammar is a non-starter :)

Comment: I was taught that it is not a matter of any gender's superiority. The reason why "le masculin l'emporte" is that there is no real masculine in French, what we call "masculine" is rather a default gender, the feminine being the only inflected gender. So *il* **is** the neutral pronoun, in a somewhat twisted way.

Comment: It's a more sensible way of seeing things, but I'm afraid the lack of masculine has forced people to believe that the default was, in fact, masculine. I for one didn't know about that.

Comment: @Joubarc Follow my lead : be an annoying pedantic linguistics fanboy and pester everyone with the fun fact :p

Comment: @Evpok Follow your lead? No, thanks. Show me gold and I may be willing.

Comment: (+1) Excellent answer. I added an answer which is quite similar to the last paragraph of yours.

Answer (score 3):

When you're writing a guide, you can choose from four options when talking to the reader:

- imperative form:
  *Cassez les œufs et battez-les.*
- infinitive form:
  *Casser les œufs et les battre.*
- impersonal form:
  *Il faut casser les œufs et les battre.*
- passive form:
  *Les œufs doivent être cassés et battus.*

Comment: +1 All the stuff on gender and pronouns is interesting but writing a guide in the third person would be very odd.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for general context are very well described in the other answers, but I just wanted to add something for mailing rules (from where I work, but I assume we aren't the only mass printing company with such rules):

- known gender (M) ⟶ *Cher client,*
- known gender (F) ⟶ *Chère cliente,*
- unknown gender ⟶ *Chère cliente, Cher client,*

Here, the need to be affable with your customers (who are more often female than male in many activities) has changed the slightly aged rule of *Le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin*…

Comment: Marketing documents as a reference for « bon usage » ?  It's the last place I would look at considering their love for anything which draw attention, especially broking rules and not respecting common usages.

Comment: A reference ? for bon usage ? Where was that stated ? I was merely adding an existing usage, which has (whether it pleases you/me or not) an influence on french language usage, yes. People read their mail, don't they ?